# How do I use AutoMapper to map multiple subclasses into one class?

Tags: c#, viewmodel, automapper, subclass

Let's assume I have three classes that are subclasses of a base class:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string BaseName { get; set; }
}

public class Subclass1 : BaseClass
{
    public string SubName1 { get; set; }
}

public class Subclass2 : BaseClass
{
    public string SubName2 { get; set; }
}

public class Subclass3 : BaseClass
{
    public string SubName3 { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to map these to a ViewModel class that looks like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string BaseName { get; set; }
    public string SubName1 { get; set; }
    public string SubName2 { get; set; }
    public string SubName3 { get; set; }
}
```

`ViewModel` simply combines the properties on all of the subclasses and flattens it. I tried to configure the mapping like so:

```
AutoMapper.CreateMap<BaseClass, ViewModel>();
```

Then I tried grabbing data from my database like so:

```
var items = Repo.GetAll<BaseClass>();
AutoMapper.Map(items, new List<ViewModel>());
```

However, what ends up happening is that only the `BaseName` property will be populated in the `ViewModel`. How would I configure AutoMapper so that it will map the properties in the subclasses as well?

Comment: Did you mean...

(different subclass names)

public class Subclass2 : BaseClass
{
    public string SubName1 { get; set; }
}

public class Subclass2 : BaseClass
{
    public string SubName2 { get; set; }
}

public class Subclass3 : BaseClass
{
    public string SubName3 { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There appears to be a bug or limitation in AutoMapper that you need corresponding TSource and TDestination hierarchies. Given:

```
public class BaseClass {
    public string BaseName { get; set; }
}

public class Subclass1 : BaseClass {
    public string SubName1 { get; set; }
}
```

You need the following view models:

```
public class ViewModel {
    public string BaseName { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModel1 : ViewModel {
    public string SubName1 { get; set; }
}
```

The following code then works:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<BaseClass, ViewModel>()
       .Include<Subclass1, ViewModel1>();
 Mapper.CreateMap<Subclass1, ViewModel1>();

 var items = new List<BaseClass> {new Subclass1 {BaseName = "Base", SubName1 = "Sub1"}};
 var viewModels = Mapper.Map(items, new List<ViewModel>());
```

Comment: If the child mapping has special resolving for members, does that map need to be created first before it is included with the parent mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AutoMapper.CreateMap<BaseClass, ViewModel>()
  .Include<Subclass1, ViewModel>()
  .Include<Subclass2, ViewModel>()
  .Include<Subclass3, ViewModel>();
AutoMapper.CreateMap<Subclass1, ViewModel>();
AutoMapper.CreateMap<Subclass2, ViewModel>();
AutoMapper.CreateMap<Subclass3, ViewModel>();

var items = Repo.GetAll<BaseClass>();
AutoMapper.Map(items, new List<ViewModel>());
```