# ASP.NET MVC : Automapper to merge class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have this code :

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like get a `List<MyClass>` MyClass look like :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string OrderCode { get; set; }
    public string OrderCreationDate { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Automapper can help me for this ?  if no other solution to avoid loop ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do DTO flattening with automapper looks at [this post](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/owainwragg/archive/2010/12/22/automapper-mapping-from-multiple-objects.aspx) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513302/how-do-i-use-automapper-to-map-multiple-subclasses-into-one-class/4513442#4513442). They should answer your question.

If you don't want to use automapper I would use a simple Linq. Something like this

```
 var myClassList = (from p in OrderModel.Orders select new MyClass()
          {
            OrderCode = p.Code,
            OrderCreationDate = p.CreationDate,
            FirstName = p.Customer.FirstName,
            LastName = p.Customer.LastName
          }).ToList();
```