# Am I using Automapper 2.0's Include functionality correctly?

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-2

Either I'm not, or it isn't working...  I have a single Source class that  I want to map to multiple views that inherit from each other.

Basically the base class is the Detail, and the child class is Edit or Update which use all the same data as Detail, plus a couple other fields to manage their own lists or whatever.

Here are the maps I'm using:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Ticket, Detail>()
                .Include<Ticket, Update>()
                .Include<Ticket, Edit>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Priority, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Priority.Code))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.TicketID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ID))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StatusCode))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Category, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProblemCategoryCode))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.crmBusCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Company.crmBusCode))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.TeamMembers, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Schedules.Where(s => s.CompleteTime == null)));

            Mapper.CreateMap<Ticket, Update>()
                .ForMember(m => m.Schedules, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => t.Schedules.Where(s => s.EmployeeID == Util.CurrentUserID() && s.CompleteTime == null)));

            Mapper.CreateMap<Ticket, Edit>();
```

Then if I Mapper.Map(ticket) any of the properties that use MapFrom don't get evaluated, they just end up with the values they'd have had if there was no set mapping.

So what's wrong here?

Comment: Which Automapper version are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an alternative solution if you don't want to call `Mapper.Map` two times. You can move the common mappings of `Detail` into an extension method:

```
public static class MappingExtensions
{
    public static IMappingExpression<Ticket, TDest> MapDetailProperties<TDest>(
         this IMappingExpression<Ticket, TDest> mapBase) where TDest : Detail
    {
        return mapBase
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Priority, 
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Priority.Code))
             ///....
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TeamMembers, 
               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src
                   .Schedules.Where(s => s.CompleteTime == null)));
    }
}
```

And then use that extension method when registering the `Ticket -> Update` and `Ticket -> Edit` mappers:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Ticket, Update>()
    .MapDetailProperties()
    .ForMember(m => m.Schedules, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => t.Schedules
        .Where(s => s.EmployeeID == Util.CurrentUserID() && 
            s.CompleteTime == null)));

Mapper.CreateMap<Ticket, Edit>()
    .MapDetailProperties();
```

Then you can use Map normally:

```
Ticket ticket = new Ticket();    
var edit = Mapper.Map<Ticket, Edit>(ticket);
var update = Mapper.Map<Ticket, Update>(ticket);
```

Comment: A bit more work, but definitely seems to be the right way to go!  Am I the only one who thinks it would make more sense for Include to basically act like this extension method?

Comment: The solution to my similar issue was a little different than this but it uses the core concept of a static extension method.  I wish AutoMapper would support this out of the box and hopefully they will in the future.

Answer (score 5):

> Am I using Automapper 2.0's Include functionality correctly?

No--When you use `.Include`, AutoMapper expects that the destination classes are in a similar hierarchy as the source classes (This is discussed further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4513302/497356)). In other words, if you were mapping to different subclasses of `Ticket` to `Detail`, `Update` and `Edit`, `Include` would be appropriate.

This doesn't seem helpful in your case. I would recommend using the overload of `.Map` that takes an existing object and modifies it. That way, you only have to define a mapping for the base type:

```
Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
Edit edit = new Edit();

Mapper.Map<Ticket, Detail>(ticket, edit); 
// Edit has now been automapped using the base mapping.

Mapper.Map<Ticket, Edit>(ticket, edit); 
// The properties unique to Edit have now been mapped.
```