# How to use AutoMapper for a source class with multiple view classes which are derived from each other

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-2

My history is mainly C/C++, but I've recently been thrown into the c#/.net world.  Please be gentle.

I'm trying to use automapper to map a single domain entity class to MULTIPLE views.  So, it is like this:

```
class DomainEntity 
{      
}
class LimitedView
{
  view with limited set of properties from DomainEntity
}    
class DeeperView : LimitedView
{
  view with a few more items from DomainEntity
}
```

So far, the only way I've been able to get this to work is to copy/paste the mappings from the base view class (LimitedView) into to mappings class for the DeeperView, which hurts my sensibilities.   I've also tried using .Include<>, but get compile errors...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Am I using Automapper 2.0's Include functionality correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863969/am-i-using-automapper-2-0s-include-functionality-correctly)

Comment: I believe I just found a duplicate of my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863969/am-i-using-automapper-2-0s-include-functionality-correctly